# Jersey 2 Client - how to get JAXBContext

Tags: jaxb, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I can find Jersey 2 documentation on [using custom JAXBContext](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e9078) but what I can't find is documentation on *reusing* its JAXBContext.

I want to be able to marshal/unmarshal entities without making an HTTP request (e.g. unmarshal some XML files on the classpath, marshal/unmarshal data for database I/O, etc.).

How can I get the `JAXBContext` instance that my Jersey 2 Client is already using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
import org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider;

import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class JaxbContextStore {
    private JaxbProvider jaxbProvider = new JaxbProvider();

    public JAXBContext getStoredJaxbContext(Class type) throws JAXBException {
        return jaxbProvider.getStoredJaxbContext(type);
    }

    private static class JaxbProvider extends AbstractJaxbProvider {
        public JaxbProvider() {
            super(null);
        }

        @Override
        public JAXBContext getStoredJaxbContext(Class type) throws JAXBException {
            return super.getStoredJaxbContext(type);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReadable(Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public Object readFrom(Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isWriteable(Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeTo(Object o, Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't figured out how to *get* the `JAXBContext` but I have figured out how to *reuse* it:

```java
client.target("file:///path/to/resource")
        .register((ClientRequestFilter) requestContext ->
                requestContext.abortWith(Response.ok()
                        .entity(new FileInputStream(Paths.get(requestContext.getUri())
                                .toFile()))
                        .build()))
        .request()
        .get(Planet.class);
```

Similar [`ClientRequestFilter`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.0/jersey/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestFilter.html)s can be used for returning strings or input streams from a database, etc. or for writing to a file-system or database.